# Python Selenium table iteration not working

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, iterator, iteration

I'm fairly new in Python Selenium, and I'm trying to automate some webscraping in an iframe.
I'm trying to get into a table (inside of the iframe) and click on a link.
All is working fine but when referencing a table column the code seems to stick to the first column's value in every iteration.
Here's some of my code:

```
1 table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='table table-striped v-align-middle']")
2 rows = table.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr")
3 for row in rows:
4     print(row.text)
5     print(row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[3]").text)
6     row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[6]//a[@href]").click()
```

Line 4 gets me the whole text of every line, perfectly working. This is just a test line.
Line 5 gets me the 3rd column value of the first row every time. So not working.
Line 6, just like Line 5, clicks on the link in column 6 but of the first row every time. So again, not working

I reckon there must be something on the xpath I'm not doing correctly?
Thanks!

I really don't get why line 4 iterates fine but line 5 and 6 stick to the first column's value every time.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the number in this xpath. ```"//td[3]"``` and the number in this xpath. ```"//td[6]//a[@href]"```. Try changing them to see what happens.

Comment: Put a dot in front of the //td. So do .//td etc. This tells to start at current row in stead of start from root

Comment: Have you already switched to the iframe before executing this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using XPath and starting a search from a given element, you must add a `.` at the start of the locator, e.g.

```
print(row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[3]").text)
                                 ^ note the period
```

Comment: Hi JeffC,
I'm getting the following error

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e6cba4f4da8c> in <module>
      3 for row in rows:
      4 
----> 5     print(row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[3]"))

Comment: You'll need to check the locator. I can't do that for your since you haven't posted the relevant HTML.

Comment: The first row didn't contain a td but a th, that's why it didn't find it. So I skipped that one and moved on, and it worked just fine. thanks!